# Configure x-frame-options response headers Spring Security 3.1

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, clickjacking

I'm trying to configure the x-frame-options response header with Spring-Security 3.1 in order to avoid ClickJacking attacks. I found that I can do it throught the XML configuration file, but it seems that it only applies to Spring Securit 3.2. Is there another way to do it with the version that I'm using?

Comment: Hi, I have the same scenario - using spring security 3.1, I don't want to upgrade to 3.2 close to the release date. Did you figure out a way to do with 3.1?